# Redirect the URl on different domain

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

My domain is

```
 https://test.org
```

From classic asp code, I redirect to Rest api URL as below

```
https://test.api.org/xyz
```

It hits my controller and wants to send redirect response to another URL

```
  string redirectResponse= "https://fake.net/mnopqrs"
  var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect);
  UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(redirectResponse);
  response.Headers.Location = uriBuilder.Uri;
  return response;
```

But rather it redirects to It redirects to URL

```
https://test.api.org/mnopqrs
```

instead

```
https://fake.net/mnopqrs
```

What I am doing wrong here. Its working fine on my local machine but not feature environment.

I tried it by using HttpStatusCode.moved instead but no success.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UrlRewrite, it might be causing this behaviour.